# Server redirecting to root vhost file

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, domain-name, lets-encrypt

Okay, I have multiple domains on my server. They have vhost conf files. my main domain.. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) has config file such as..

```
    ServerAdmin example@example.net
    ServerName example.net
    ServerAlias www.example.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.net/public_html
```

I have 2 files for it..  80 and 443 for SSL

Now the issue is this.. When I type in a browser [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it takes me to root folder of domain instead of site folder root that's in the path.

when I type example.com into the browser it takes me to the correct root. I can not find this issue anywhere or how to solve i've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You might have another `VirtualHost` that matches the `www.example.com` and appears before in the configuration. That configuration would be used, instead.

A very common mistake is omitting `ServerName` in the default (or any) virtualhost. If no `ServerName` is specified, the server attempts to deduce it from the server's IP address, and this may result in `www.example.com`, making it unintuitively the first matching virtualhost instead of the one actually having it as a `ServerName` or in `ServerAlias`.

Answer (score 0):

need to verify the virtual host configuration for domain example.com.

ServerName example.com

ServerAlias www.example.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to file names of the conf. Add 0-{yourfile}.conf, 1-{yourfile}.conf etc. Just add a prefix of the order number to each file. Apache execute that way so.